# Mypy/typeshed stubs for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing

Just checking to see if anybody listening has already generated a sort-of-working set of mypy/typeshed stubs for `pandas`. I naively ran stubgen over the local pandas install which generated some errors. I can go with what I have to start with, but was hoping someone else had pushed the ball further. (Nothing obvious turned up on GitHub, though there is an old ticket for stubs.)

Answer (score 21):

By now (March 2021) there is [a dedicated pandas stub project](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/) in progress. It is however not developed by the pandas team (thanks to @remeus for pointing that out). The `data-science-types` project is deprecated. On GitHub [they write](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types):

> ⚠️ this project has mostly stopped development ⚠️
>
> The pandas team and the numpy team are both in the process of integrating type stubs into their codebases, and we don't see the point of competing with them.

The `NumPy` stubs used to be in a separate project, but now [have been merged](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs) into the main git repo:

> These stubs have been merged into NumPy, and all further development will happen in the NumPy main repo. We welcome your contributions there!

In July 2022, the pandas-stubs package will be integrated into the pandas GitHub project http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs. [They write](https://github.com/VirtusLab/pandas-stubs):

> Starting from July 2022 pandas_stubs package will no longer be sourced from here but instead from a repository owned and maintained by the core pandas team

Comment: **Misleading answer** since _pandas-stubs_ is not developed by _pandas_

Comment: @remeus Thanks for your correction. Are you happy with the new version? Btw. if you want people to notice/correct their mistakes it would be helpful to @ mention them so they get notified.

Comment: Update: In June/July 2022, this `pandas-stubs` package will be integrated into the `pandas` GitHub organization https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs

Comment: @felice do you have a source for that?

Comment: @user2640045 Yes, in the original repo: "Starting from July 2022 pandas_stubs package will no longer be sourced from here but instead from a repository owned and maintained by the core pandas team" https://github.com/VirtusLab/pandas-stubs

Answer (score 6):

I have not yet found stubs for `pandas`. However, someone [has created](https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-data/tree/master/numpy-mypy) some for NumPy.

One interim option could be to define a custom type according to how mypy sees pandas objects. When I wrap a `DataFrame` object in `reveal_type(df)` and run mypy, it reveals that the recognized type signature is

```
Union[builtins.dict[Union[builtins.str, builtins.int], builtins.dict[Any, Any]], Any]
```

However it shows the same for a `Series` object, so it's not very accurate.

Answer (score 6):

As of June 2020, pandas doesn't have stubs yet, but there [is some progress](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14468) in that direction. By now, you can use the `data-science-types` package ([on GitHub](https://github.com/predictive-analytics-lab/data-science-types)) which provides stub files for `pandas`, `numpy` and `matplotlib`, though it's also a work in progress.

Answer (score 6):

As of July 2022 check out https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs.

> This is the home for pandas typing stubs supported by the pandas core team. The stubs are likely incomplete in terms of covering the published API of pandas.