# mypy missed incompatible type in case of a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: pandas, mypy

I've tripped on mypy not complaining about incompatible types when DataFrame is involved.  It's likely me being new to mypy, so please point me in the right direction.

I've simplified the case to the following code. My intuition tells me that both lines 12 and 13 should fail. But line 13: `func(DataFrame())` for some reason passes.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

class T1:
    pass

class T2:
    pass

def func(arg: T2):
    pass

func(T1())
func(DataFrame())
```

```sh
mypy mypy_sandbox.py 
mypy_sandbox.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "T1"; expected "T2"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: It seems that mypy is treating `DataFrame` as `Any`. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, maybe it's something missing in pandas for now (Dec 2021).
Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423878/17691719) given by [@user2640045](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640045/user2640045), I've tried to install *pandas-stubs* and it solved my issue.

```sh
pip install pandas-stubs
Successfully installed pandas-stubs-1.2.0.39
```

```sh
mypy mypy_sandbox.py 
mypy_sandbox.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "T1"; expected "T2"  [arg-type]
mypy_sandbox.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "DataFrame"; expected "T2"  [arg-type]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Yes looks good, see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs.